# AMCocoaPod not found

Tags: cocoapods

I am working with one of the existing project with pod . My pod file consist of the     `pod 'AMCocoaPod'` but while `pod install` I am getting error message there.Also when I am searching for **AMCocoaPod** here :https://cocoapods.org/?q=AMCocoaPod , I am not getting anything. So due to this my application throwing error saying :`#import "UIView+AMAdditions.h" not found`  . Please let me know what is the problem , also Is there any other option where I can find  **"UIView+AMAdditions.h"**

Comment: what is the github repo for this AMCocoaPod?

Comment: i am also not finding anything for this

Comment: Then probably, this does not exist. Where did you read about this pod or any link that I can go through. I did a google search and found nothing.

Comment: I also searched here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/ and found nothing.

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as correct, if AMCocoaPod indeed does not exist in your searches as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no cocoapods repo present for this library, you would not get this from pod install.

You can find the code here:

https://github.com/cpart/iOS_pods_source/blob/1e7156c40d49598a9b3dd7469171fe3084be5c4e/AMCocoaPod/AMCocoaPod/Categories/UIView%2BAMAdditions.h

https://github.com/cpart/iOS_pods_source/blob/1e7156c40d49598a9b3dd7469171fe3084be5c4e/AMCocoaPod/AMCocoaPod/Categories/UIView%2BAMAdditions.m